# How to pass on data from form and parse using tpl in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I have designed a form and wanted to generate output using tpl file.

All the examples in sench provided scenarios where the "data" attribute is prepopulated with some json or xml data and how we renderit using "tpl".

Pls see the code :

#### #

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<script>
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.define("customLink",{
        xtype:"link",
        extend:"Ext.Component",
        tpl:'<div style="margin:40px 40px"><a style="font-size:32px;text-transform: capitalize" href="{url}">{text}</a><div style="margin-top:20px">{paragraph}</div></div>',
        initComponent:function(){
            this.data={
                text:this.text,
                url:this.url,
                paragraph:this.paragraph
            };
            this.callParent(arguments);
        },
        renderTo:Ext.getBody()
    });
    Ext.create("customLink",{"text":"google","url":"http://www.google.com","paragraph":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

#### #

The Above code will generate a Heading with hyperlink followed by a paragraph.

Now what if I want to provide the link,title text and paragraph using a form with 2 textfields( one for title,one for url) and 1 textarea(for paragraph) components.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I would not recommend to try rendering components into the tpl.

Comment: Do you want to render the Link using the Data from Form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the data from form using `var formData = form.getForm().getValues()` 
and update the link using `link.update(formData)`

```
var form = this.up('form');
link.update(form.getForm().getValues());
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/189e